# SQL Where Column Contains Array of Json

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to query a column that contains an array of json objects.

The array of object looks like this:

```
[
{
    "TYPE": "car",
    "NAME": "lucy"
},
{
    "TYPE": "bus",
    "NAME": "bob"
},
{
    "TYPE": "car",
    "NAME": "mary"
}
]
```

I am trying to select if the column contains objects with type = "car" and name = "lucy"

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Have you even tried something? Like Google it? I got this result at the first search: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15.

Comment: What query do you have so far? What is the table definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use `OPENJSON` to break out the array into separate rows:**

```sql
SELECT j.*
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.) WITH (
    [TYPE] varchar(50),
    [NAME] varchar(50)
) j
WHERE j.[TYPE] = 'car' AND j.[NAME] = 'lucy'
```

Or if you want to just filter the main table based on that, put it inside a `WHERE`

```sql
SELECT t.*
FROM YourTable t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM OPENJSON(t.) WITH (
        [TYPE] varchar(50),
        [NAME] varchar(50)
    ) j
    WHERE j.[TYPE] = 'car' AND j.[NAME] = 'lucy'
);
```